# Searching for a string from a line number in both directions

Tags: python, string, search, variables

Using Python 2.4, I am reading a large flat file and picking a particular line number. Now I want to search for a string, say, `START` before that line number, and a string `END`, after that line number.

How do I get the line numbers of the nearest occurrences of the strings `START` (before current line number) and `END` (after current line number)?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
line_no = 1

# Seek the last START before reaching the target line.
start_line_no = -1
while line_no != target_line_no:
    line = input.readline()
    if line == "":
        # File is shorter than you think.
        break
    line_no += 1
    if START in line:
        start_line_no = line_no

# Seek the first END after the target line.    
end_line_no = -1
while true:
    line = input.readline()
    if line == "":
        # END could not be found.
        break
    line_no += 1
    if END in line:
        end_line_no = line_no
        break

print start_line_no, end_line_no
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. But say that I am using a very large file, and the content I'm looking for is around the middle of the file. Wouldn't it be quite intensive to search for each line from the beginning? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Get it correct first, then measure, then see if you need to optimize. Premature optimization based on what you guess will be inefficient is the root of all Evil.

Comment: If the lines have arbitrary lengths, than no, there is no more efficient way than this (other than preprocessing the file for future operations).

Sequential file access is a super fast operation. I would try that before looking for tricky optimizations.